# Search for a constant Metric $\eta$ satisfying the a condition

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I am looking for a $2 \times 2$ constant metric $\eta$, satisfying  the following condition:

$\eta A \eta^{-1}= A^T$.

where 
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
    a & b \\
    c & d
    \end{bmatrix}$$

Could anyone please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rearranging the equation
$$\eqalign{
NAN^{-1} &= A^T \implies A^{-T}NA = N \cr
}$$
and vectorizing both sides yields
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}(N) &= (A^T\otimes A^{-T}){\,\rm vec}(N) \cr
n &= Kn \cr
}$$
So $n$ is any eigenvector of the Kronecker matrix $(K)$ corresponding to an eigenvalue of one, 

and $N$ can be recovered by reshaping the eigenvector into a $2\times 2$ matrix.

The matrix $K$ and its eigenvalues/vectors will change with every $A$, so I don't see how the metric $(N)$ could possibly be constant for all $A$.